# Remove Gridlines in Excel HTML embed

Tags: html, css, excel

I created a spreadsheet in Excel and saved as a web page.  I "unchecked" View and Print gridlines under Page Layout, however, once I embed the page into my site, the gridlines are visible.  I have played around with the CSS to attempt to eliminate the gridlines to no avail.  Unfortunately, the code has to many characters to post here but, you can view my test page here: http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html

This may or may not be a simple fix but any assistance or input would be appreciated.

CSS

```
<!--table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
.xl154614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:black;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl654614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:white;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:italic;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Patua One", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#FF6600;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl664614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:white;
    font-size:3.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:italic;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Patua One", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:white;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl674614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:white;
    font-size:3.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:italic;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Patua One", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:black;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl684614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:black;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl694614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:#0563C1;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl704614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:#0563C1;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
.xl714614
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:black;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Candara;
    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#D8D8D8;
    mso-pattern:black none;
    white-space:nowrap;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stylesheet, you have to set the table cell's borders to none.

If you want to take a shortcut you could just do:

```
td, tr {
  border-style: none
}
```

That would cover all cells on your page.

Comment: is that as opposed to "0" or is this something I have to add?  Thanks for your help.  I appreciate.

Comment: If you could post your stylesheet or whatever code that's styling your table it would help figure out exactly what's causing your issue.

Comment: Okay, I posted a snippet of the CSS.  As I mentioned above, there are too many characters to post on here.  I'm guessing that I will have to add the "border: none;" attribute to every individual cell?  Let me know what you think and, again, thanks for the help.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a shortcut, but what you said would work as well.